# How can I change font rendering to sub-pixel BGR ordering?

Tags: 11.10, fonts

In Ubuntu 11.10, I can't find a way to change the sub-pixel byte ordering to BGR. I have a BGR monitor and fonts look blurry because of this. I've installed `gnome-tweak-tool` but I can't find an option for the sub-pixel ordering. This used to be easy to do with the old font settings window.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this using a GUI (`dconf-editor` from the package `dconf-tools`) or on the command-line:

#### GUI

1. Open `dconf-editor`
2. In the left pane, go to */org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings*
3. In the right pane, change the value of the *rgba-order* key to *bgr*:

[image]

#### Command-line

Just run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings rgba-order 'bgr'
```

Comment: What if I have one monitor in portrait, and another in landscape? Can I set the subpixel order for each monitor independently? AFAICT, this is unpossible, but perhaps, I'm missing something?

Comment: Also, Chrome does not seem to use this setting. Is there a way I can set this in Chrome?

Comment: Command -line for gsettings worked perfectly here, thanks!

Comment: @allyourcode Looking at some possibly related bug reports at http://crbug.com/ it seems like Chrome does not really support vertical subpixel layouts and switching to grayscale AA seems to be the only alternative (go to `chrome://flags/#lcd-text-aa` for that).

Answer (score 8):

You also may want to change system-wide font settings (and re-login afterwards):

```
ln -s ../conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-bgr.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d
```

This fixes sub-pixel rendering on Google Chrome for me, too.

Comment: This no longer seems to work with Google Chrome version 75.0. I, too, have a BGR display and both Chrome and Firefox do incorrect subpixel rendering.

Comment: This worked for me in ubuntu 23.04, after chrome and other applications *stopped* respecting the settings in dconf. make sure to also delete `10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf` in the same folder!

Answer (score 1):

In latest ubuntu versions (such as 22.10) sub-pixel ordering (RGB/BGR/VRGB/VBGR) is set in dconf-editor under path /org/gnome/desktop/interface/font-rgba-order - such as shown on this screenshot [image]